# hover state background color lost after javascript script execution

Tags: jquery

The original jquery:

```
$('#container section').each(function() {
                $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
                    var anchorRef = 'a[href="#' + this.id + '"]';
                    if (direction === 'down') {
                        $(anchorRef).animate({'backgroundColor' : 'rgb(230, 77, 78)'});
                    } else {
                        $(anchorRef).animate({'backgroundColor' : 'rgb(25, 25, 25)'});
                    }
                });
            });
```

The CSS:

```
.main-menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

The problem is that, once that animation finishes, if we return to that element, the hover effect doesn't get applied any longer.

Any clue why?

I've tried to "force" the overstate on the script like this:

```
$('#container section').each(function() {
                $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
                    var anchorRef = 'a[href="#' + this.id + '"]';
                    var anchorRefHover = 'a[href="#' + this.id + '"]:hover';//NEW
                    if (direction === 'down') {
                        $(anchorRef).animate({'backgroundColor' : 'rgb(230, 77, 78)'});
                        $(anchorRefHover).css({backgroundColor : '#333'});//NEW
                    } else {
                        $(anchorRef).animate({'backgroundColor' : 'rgb(25, 25, 25)'});
                        $(anchorRefHover).css({backgroundColor : '#333'});//NEW
                    }
                });
            });
```

Still lost the hover effect market on the CSS.

I added !important on the CSS hover rule. That triggers the hover.
But the reason while I prefer doing it using javascript its because,
**the hover background color should only apply if the element we have hover doesn't have the background rgb(230, 77, 78)**

Not sure if it will work, but I'm thinking about adding !important via javascript when the above is the case... but perhaps there's a better way?

Any clue to help me out?

Note:
Here's the Fiddle thanks to koala_dev efford:

http://jsfiddle.net/talofo/5YgY5/5/

Comment: You can load external files on the left of jsfiddle

Comment: How about using CSS transitions for the change in background that you can control by adding/removing a class, then you can modify your CSS accordingly to only apply the rule when the class is not there

Comment: If so on the left go to external resources type in the url the click add

Comment: @koala_dev - Are you suggesting to drop the animate()? If that's the case, I can't simply do that, because the animate will allow me to fade in and out, something that the addClass removeClass will not do I believe.

Comment: With CSS transitions you can get the same effect ([where they are supported](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions))

Comment: I'd go with transitions. jQuery animations use inline styles on the element to achieve their effects. Inline styles have higher specificity than any other css, so they override your classes

Comment: This needs to work with ie8 at least. No dice for CSS 3 transitions I believe.

Comment: @MEME here, I've included the waypoint library in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YgY5/), update it to add your markup, CSS and JS code

Comment: hmm. As an alternative, you could add the class `normal` to the element, and trigger the hover on that class. Then you toggle that class after animation. eg `.main-menu ul li a.normal:hover { background-color: #333; }` and `$(anchorRef).toggleClass('normal');`

Comment: Here's a working fiddle that reproduces the problem http://jsfiddle.net/5YgY5/4/

Comment: with small fix to reactivate hover: http://jsfiddle.net/5YgY5/9/

Comment: Thank you both for being with me. I was here for hours. And, the solution seems so logical now, I'm always wondering, "why was I unable to find solutions like you both did?" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DomDay noted in the comment, jQuery `.animate()` uses inline styles that override your CSS rules, so one solution would be to remove the inline statement when you revert the color to the original one like this:

```
$(anchorRef).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgb(25, 25, 25)'},function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YgY5/8/)

Comment: so, that will animate as intended and make the anchor background to 25,25,25 and, once it finishes, we remove that style attribute, resulting on an element that is "ready" to receive the CSS hover rule. Is this correct ?